# Best processor for visualization and no-3D proccessing

Tags: c#, winforms

There is a project which I have been working on and the end-program will require a new PC and lots of processing power. I would like to know - are there any things that I should know before buying a new PC?

These are conditions:

- Program will be written in `C# winforms`
- as well will work from within `virtual machine` (ex. vmware) but not limited to it.
- Program does NOT process any graphics (`no 3D` and `no 2D` processing)
- Program is used `for analysis` of an input data and `calculations` (lots of in-memory processing rather than file-processing).

And these are the questions:

1. Win 8 x64 vs Win 7 x64?
2. APU or CPU + GPU. Since I do not need 3D processing - shouldn't APU be enough?
3. AMD or Intel. I heard that Intels are best for visualization. Still true?

as you can see my main concern is the processor (and OS). Any advices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion generally any latest-ish PC with quad core (and above) processor and over 8-10 gb of RAM should be good. I have always used Intel CPU so will vote for it.

But that is not the only thing required for successfully running your software the way you want. Performance doesn't come only from latest and greatest hardware. No matter how powerful your hardware is, unless the software makes use of more than single cpu, it's useless. If your threads are locking-up over shared resource the new shiny hardware won't help. Meaning, best hardware is not the only thing you should look for to get good performance.

I will suggest to go for a virtual solution such as vmware Esxi server where you can change your hardware configuration for your VM on the fly depending on your hardware requirements. Of course in that case, get the server hardware with highest specs that you can afford.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of many requirement for this as C# WinForms don't really draw a lot of processing power. If you have no graphics then AMD or Intel won't make much of a difference.

One thing I can think of however is Intel VT-d which allows you to virtualize directed-io. Basically, if you buy 2 hard drives, you can delegate one directly to your Virtual Machine (VMWare supports this on some versions like workstation). This way your host OS won't interfere with data transfers within your VM.

SSD is also a big plus.

Again, WinForms are not that expensive to execute.